# switching the layers on/off in leaflet map layer tree based on styling

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet

I am developing web application which has leaflet maps. I need the layer control which is similar to QGIS

[image: layer control]

I am using Geoserver to get the layer as wms format and I added that layer using tilelayer.wms function. I am using jstree plugin for tree like structure of layers. So when user checks any layer I added that layer using map.addLayer() function. When user unchecks the layer I used map.removeLayer() function.
So now question is I want to add or remove the layer based on it's style like this

[image]

How to achieve this functionality using leaflet and geoserver and jstree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the it worked by layer.setParams() function in leaflet